# React Warning - Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to export many images that are located at src/assets folder (to make it easy to be called through my whole project).

I got a **warning** that says:

> Line 38:1:  Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export

Codes:

src/constants/images.js:

```
import email from '../assets/email.png';
import mobile from '../assets/mobile.png';
import api from '../assets/api.png';
//...

export default {                   //Line 38
    email,
    mobile,
    api,
    //...
};
```

src/constants/index.js:

```
export { default as images } from './images'
```

Navbar.jsx: (I am importing theses images here in this Navbar code through index.js)

```
import { images } from "../../constants";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div>
        <img src={images.logo} alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; the [rule docs](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md) explain the warning, the warning says explicitly what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry, i will edit my question to make it more lucid

Comment: The warning is because the exported object isn't assigned to a variable before being exported as the default. You can fix it by assigning the exported object to a variable before exporting it as the default (which is what the warning message says to do), or you can disable the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
export {
    email,
    mobile,
    api,
    //...
};
```

instead of what you're trying to do.

But if you  want to export it as default, then you should do

```
const IMAGES = {
  email,
  mobile,
  api,
  //...
};

export default IMAGES;
```